# Friendly_Id 5.0 -> RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

In my model I have the following:

```
class Dyno < ActiveRecord::Base  
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, :use => [:slugged, :history, :finders]

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    car.present? && horsepower_changed?
  end

  def slug_candidates
    [
      [car.owner, :horsepower, "horsepower-dyno"],
      [car.owner, car.nickname, :horsepower, "horsepower-dyno"]
    ]
  end
```

When I try to update a record:
Before a slug is generated, I have no problem running my validations and getting all my validation messages, but soon as the slug is generated, and i hit save I get 404. Even if i put in all the proper fields, and hit save which would pass validations it is not saving the record and returning a 404

It's looks like it's trying to look up and save the record by the new "-slug-" before that slug exists in the record.

```
Started PATCH "/dynos/john-smith-1800-horsepower-dyno" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-09 12:50:03 -0400
Processing by DynosController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rxz8PPyTYgQx6umBB7t50fLtPUk4zGrCmSiwd751jxI=", "dyno"=>{"car_id"=>"1", "horsepower"=>"1800", "torque"=>"555", "boost"=>"", "nitrous"=>"no", "nitrous_amount"=>"", "fuel_id"=>"2", "tuner"=>"", "video_url"=>"", "dyno_brand_id"=>"", "details"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Dyno", "id"=>"john-smith-1800-horsepower-dyno"}
  [1m[35mDyno Load (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT "dynos".* FROM "dynos" INNER JOIN "friendly_id_slugs" ON "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_id" = "dynos"."id" AND "friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = 'Dyno' WHERE ("friendly_id_slugs"."sluggable_type" = 'Dyno' AND "friendly_id_slugs"."slug" = 'john-smith-1800-horsepower-dyno') ORDER BY "dynos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms
```

In my controller I am using the .friendly scope

```
def set_dyno
  @dyno = Dyno.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

Also, in my controller I am doing a save in the new action so that i can let users add associated pictures from the same new view. Could maybe Friendly_Id may be reacting to a nil slug in a existing record?

> ```
> def new
>   @dyno = Dyno.new
>   @dyno.save :validate => false   
> end
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using friendly_id 5.0.2

Comment: Is `params[:id]` the friendly id? or an integer?

Comment: :id is an integer,
:slug is my friendly_id field

Comment: @JoelGrannas Did you got answer of it or is it resolved for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove friendly from Dyno.

```
friendly.find(params[:id])
```

as you are using finder here

```
friendly_id :slug_candidates, :use => [:slugged, :history, :finders]
```